# VPN server on Windows Server 2008 for a small office

Tags: vpn, virtualization, windows-server-2008, openvpn

I'm going to refurbish the IT-infrastructure for a small organization with one single office, and I'm not sure what VPN server to use. In your opinion, would the built-in Windows Server 2008 VPN server suffice or are there any specific problems with it as opposed to, for example, OpenVPN?

I'd rather run a Windows native VPN server, but if there are few (preferably free) good alternatives, I could install VMware ESXi and virtualize both Windows and an OpenVPN-server. By the way, because of a low budget this office runs a solution with only one physical server.

Any advice would be great to help me grasp this field of which I'm quite a novice. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't this also covered in your [Revamping an old and unstable office IT-solution using Windows Server and OpenVPN](http://serverfault.com/questions/218692/revamping-an-old-and-unstable-office-it-solution-using-windows-server-and-openvpn)?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find it easier to keep VPN off the servers, and use a VPN appliance or router instead.  For example, Cisco 851W, Draytek 2820 or Netgear VPN firewall routers or even Tomato/DD-WRT powered home routers with OpenVPN (like the Netgear WNR3500L or Asus RTN-16), if you are on a budget.

Comment: I'm considering putting OpenVPN on an extra PC in my office.  Anybody had any success with this?